# Create new custom projections in QGIS 3.12?

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3, coordinates, proj

QGIS does not have the coordinate reference system I need, So I decide to define a new custom Geographic coordinate system. To define a CRS, I selected customProjection Custom CRS from the Settings menu. The Custom Coordinate Reference System Definition dialog requires only two parameters to define a user CRS:
1) A descriptive name
2) The cartographic parameters in PROJ.4 format

So I did that as you can see from the picture:
[image]

But when I click OK to add the projection within QGIS a pop up message with an error show up and with very different set of parameters in the parameter window. the error message says I have set up a proj string definition equivalent to esri:102218 which is not really the same. I don't really know if this a bug or something went wrong with my parameter setting.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select the **WKT Format** (not the Proj String as shown in the question screenshot)

https://epsg.io/4919
copy text function

[image]

**Then Validate**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your new CRS, but with an old CRS defined before the upgrade to 3.12 version.

That CRS is a Generated CRS. In older versions, when you load a layer with an unknown CRS, a custom CRS was created.

Now, the ESRI authority was added to the PROJ database, custom CRSes are not automatically generated, and custom definitions that are equal to a known CRS are not allowed.

Just remove that old automatically generated CRS, you will not need it any more.

Comment: I have a similar issue trying to create a Mercator projection with a new pole and 40deg rotation. If I use the PROJ option in Qgis 3.16.11 it says the CRS matches the world Merc EPSG. Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Hi, feel free to create a new question for that topic.