# Recenter projection of world map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, equal-area, mollweide

I'm a beginner in QGIS. I would like to use world maps with different longitudes in the centre for my geography lessons.
I am trying to create world maps centred on different longitudes (others than Greenwich).
The projection should be an equal area one, if possible the Mollweide projection.
Does anyone have step to step instructions?

Comment: Have a look at https://epsg.io/54009, the well known text (WKT) definition has parameters that can be customized, you can specify a value other than 0 in PARAMETER["central_meridian",<your value here>] to centre the projection to anywhere you like. Read https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358719/create-new-custom-projections-in-qgis-3-12, this post has instructions on how to use a WKT custom coordinate reference system.